# What a member of the sentence is it?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "I think desire to be smart is a normal thing" what a tipe of members of a sentence Is "smart" regarding the infinitive "to be"? Is it a direct object, complex subject or something else? As I know, an adjective can't be direct object at all (and to be isn't a transitive verb but a linking one so it's can't have a direct object even in a theory) nor an subject complement if "to be" isn't a predicate in the context mentioned above. So, what a member of the sentence is "smart" ?

Comment: "Smart" is predicative complement of the verb "be". "(That) desire to be smart is a normal thing" is a content clause functioning as complement of "think". Within that clause "desire to be smart" is the subject and "is a normal thing" is the predicate. Btw, "**the** desire ..." might be preferable.

Comment: How can it be predicative complement if to be isn't a predicate?

Comment: The subject of the content clause is the NP "desire to be smart", which consists of "desire" as head and the infinitival clause "to be smart" as complement. The infinitival clause has "to be smart" as predicate.